# twitter bootstrap icons are not showing,when assets is serving through amazon cdn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am working on RoR. Using twitter bootstarp for my website front end design. And planning to use amazon cdn as asset host. I pushed all the static files to amazon. I am using amazon-s3 as cdn origin. Pushed the sprite images **glyphicons-halflings** and **glyphicons-halflings-white** in to the cdn and importing it to **bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less** like

```
@iconSpritePath: asset-path("icons/glyphicons-halflings");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path("icons/glyphicons-halflings-white");
```

But it is not working. Then I created a separate **icon.css.less** created styles for each image separately.

But still the icons are not taking effect. All the other styles are taking effect and there is only a problem for icons. Can anyone give any suggestions. I am totally stuck on this.

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Can you post the generated css to see what path was actually used as a replacement for your @iconxxx variables?

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail and show your configuration settings, source code or even the website you are working on.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. Ya We have solved the issue by pre-compiling the assets and pushing in to amazon using asset sync

Answer (score 1):

On your bootstrap.less file make sure you have this line

```
@import "sprites.less";
```

This less file provides the class "icon" to use the icons. Then you can use it this way:

```
<i class="icon icon-file"></i>
```